# Batch to run a MSI package multiple times successfully

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-installer

I have written the following code, to run a single.msi package multiple times however it runs only once successfully and gives "Repair" or "Uninstall" option the very next time.
I need to get this resolved and have it run multiple times.

I have read that I need to author a transform(.mst) for this type of action to be performed successfully but unsure how to do it.

Please note that "OID_VALUE" & "LOGGING_SERVICE_URI_VALUE" are values that I need to pass for the .msi package to run.

```
@echo OFF

setLocal enableDELAYedexpansion

:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO Select the Environment you are running the batch
ECHO.
ECHO    1.  UAT
ECHO    2.  Production
ECHO    3.  EXIT
ECHO.
CHOICE /C 123 /N /M "Select option:"
if errorlevel 3 EXIT                                                                                
if errorlevel 2 goto PROD                                      
if errorlevel 1 goto UAT

:UAT
set URI=https://log.acdmuat.appleclouds.com/LoggingService/
GOTO LOGGINGURI

:PROD
set URI=https://log.acdm.appleclouds.com/LoggingService/

:LOGGINGURI
for /f "delims=" %%a in (oid.txt) do (
msiexec /q /l* c:\temp\installer.log /i 
"C:\AHSInstall\Apple\Apple.msi" OID_VALUE="%%a" LOGGING_SERVICE_URI_VALUE=%URI%
)

Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working exactly as it is supposed to.  After you have run it once the package is installed.  So on subsequent installs your choices are probably Uninstall or Repair.  If you think there are other options... (like maybe Modify) do this:

```
"C:\AHSInstall\Apple\Apple.msi" /?
```

That should show you the options avaiable to you.

Comment: :- what i want it to do is install for a new instance, however it only gives option to uninstall or repair, i need it to restart the installation again...please let me know if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

An installed product is defined by its ProductCode (and PackageCode) so if you want to install the same product again then you must change the ProductCode (and PackageCode) then you have a different product that will install. Obviously if everything else is the same (shortcuts, file locations, registry entries etc) then you're going to be overwriting files, registry entries, shortcuts, and so on, so there is plenty of opportunity for strange behavior.

If on the other hand you with to replace the existing product with a new version containing updated files and so on then you need a major upgrade to install the  new product and replace the old one.  However you haven't really described your ultimate goal - you've decided that you have a solution that requires reinstalling the MSI, but we don't know that ultimate goal.